# Method function pointer template without naming class type

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, syntactic-sugar

Consider this `template` function, invoking a method of an object of `class T`.

```
template<class T, void (T::*Method)()>
void circuitousInvoke(T* callee) {
    (callee->*Method)();
}
```

Example:

```
struct A {
    void test() {};
}

circuitousInvoke<A, &A::test>(new A);
```

As the type T is already known to circuitousInvoke from parameter `callee`, is there a way to avoid typing this type?

```
circuitousInvoke<&A::test>(new A);
```

### EDIT

This question refers to template functions only. Inheritance and other class based solutions are not suitable in this case. (In my project using a wrapper object would be more worse than typing an additional name.)

Comment: here is how it can be done in c++11 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28892710/4117728

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ - is it possible to extract class and argument types from a member function type in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783876/c-is-it-possible-to-extract-class-and-argument-types-from-a-member-function)

Comment: @tobi303: Not a duplicate, because he doesn't *have* a member function type, he has a member function pointer... which can't even be made a template parameter in C++14 and below, unless its type is named.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be possible in C++17 with `auto`

```
template<auto Method, typename T>
void circuitousInvoke(T* callee) {
    (callee->*Method)();
}
```

and then

```
A a;
circuitousInvoke<&A::test>(&a);
```

Comment: gcc already supports `-std=C++17` (with that feature), clang supports `-std=c++1z`